# How to setting the speech rate in Azure text to speech?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

Hello I am trying to configure the speech rate using python with the text to speech services. I need the parameter statement.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @ [yutongtie-msft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/yutongtie-msft/) , Your answer helped lot.

There are two ways to change the speed rate for Text to Speech.

1. Create a **custom voice**. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/custom-neural-voice#the-basics-of-custom-neural-voice)
2. **SSML language**: use the SSML language to control the speaking speed.  You can change to use SSML as input to call speech service. Then it can change the speech rate.

   The   [`prosody`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup?tabs=csharp#adjust-prosody) element is used to specify changes to pitch, contour, range, **rate**, duration, and volume for the Text-to-Speech output.

`< prosody pitch="value" contour="value" range="value" rate="value" duration="value" volume="value"> < /prosody>`

**Rate** Indicates the speaking rate of the text. You can express rate as:

A relative value, expressed as a number that acts as a multiplier of the default. For example, a value of *1* results in no change in the rate. A value of *0.5* results in a halving of the rate. A value of *3* results in a tripling of the rate.

A constant value:

- x-slow
- List item
- slow
- medium
- fast
- x-fast
- default

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/664865/in-text-to-speech-python-api-what-is-the-parameter.html)